# Как настроить размещение базы данных для каждого проекта по отдельности

Tags: java, mysql

как настроить размещение базы данных для каждого проекта по отдельности? Изменение пути datadir в файле my.ini общий для всех баз, я хочу оставить базу в проекте и запускать на любом компьютере без предварительной настройки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При подключению к БД не указывается путь размещения базы. Указывается только адрес сервера и **имя** базы данных.

Т.е. вам не нужно изменять никаких конфигурационных файлов. Вам нужно только на конкретный сервер залить конкретную базу

Comment: Ок, но если я перенесу свою базу, например в папку sql  в проекте, то она работать не будет или будет?

Comment: @ДмитрийСеров Нет. Пока вы ее не развернете средствами сервера

Comment: Спасибо за ответ